# Bored with the job

Tags: work-environment, job-change

I am getting bore with my job.I love  development but I feel very tired or feel sleepy when I start to code at work but when I work for my own projects it feels energetic & never get tired.May I change the job or can any 1 suggest me how 2 kill boredom?

Comment: Jobs aren't exciting; people are. That's why it's called work. Stop expecting to be entertained and start thinking about the people who could use your software and make "their" job/life less boring.

Comment: Either you're breaking rocks, or building cathedrals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is - find another job.

The longer answer is find another job but with more information:

I'm of the opinion that when you become unhappy with your job it's time to move on. Getting 'sleepy' or 'bored' with the things you work on is normal if it happens occasionally. We all have things we have to do that are boring. But when you start finding all of your tasks boring you have a serious problem. Let's break this down into some discrete steps.

Step1 - find out what, specifically, is boring to you and what is interesting. You say your personal projects are 'interesting' but there's probably something more to that. Would you still find them interesting after working on them for 40 hours a week for a few months? Are they interesting because they are in their early stages/easier(in some ways) and you are making regular progress with them? Are they interesting because they are yours and no one else is 'making' you do them? Are they a different subject material than your work related projects?

Let's take a step and examine some of these reasons a bit more closely. The easiest to answer and fix would be that you work projects and  projects are using different technologies or are different subject material. This could be resolved by trying different technologies at your work projects or looking for projects that more closely align with your interest. This may involve finding a new employer that has has projects such as those you are interested in. The other reasons are a bit harder. A lot of time programmers, especially, forget the honeymoon period of a project. It's that early time period when you're doing the easy things and racking up tons of wins. You're writing TONs of code and most of it works. But that honeymoon period doesn't last for any project. Eventually you're down to the nuances and bug fixes. If your personal projects are more fun because they are new, you're still in the honeymoon period or because you haven't spent enough time to really get to know their challenges then this feeling is something that may pass in time. Finally if the issue is simply that you find projects you are working on for yourself more enjoyable than projects you are working on for someone else - you may have to decide between boring work for someone else or trying to work for yourself. Of course it goes, almost, without saying that the base reason could be any number of reasons, a combination of reasons or something totally illogical...

Step2 - Once you've identified the base 'cause' start making moves to change it. If it's the subject matter that's boring you start looking into resources to buff up your skills in the subject matter that interests you. If the long term goal is to start working for yourself - start putting in those after-work hours to get your project up and running! In short once you've spent the time diagnosing the problem, spend some time getting prepared to apply the solution. Maybe take some classes, maybe find a new hobby, maybe do what you need to find a new job.

Step3 - Do all the stuff you prepped for in step 2.

Step4 - profit. Hopefully, at the end of this, you'll be less bored with your work or you'll have come to a healthy balance between boredom and excitement. There's always going to be some level of boredom or unhappiness in your life. You can and should always be taking the time to identify and apply solutions to these. That is, after all, how we grow as people.

Comment: There is some good advice here about looking at the causes of boredom, just looking for another job is running away. All jobs have boring times, you need to learn to work when you are bored and to not expect excitement. There is also no mitgating advice to work for ways to make the current job more interesting. Suppose it is because you don't like being in maintenance nmode, perhaps you can stay the same job and get assigned to work on some new projects.  Maybe you need to do a differnt kind of programming, but even then you may find that it gets more boring when you have to do it every day.

Answer (score 2):

Answers to this question can be very broad, It's hard to tell what will do it for you since everyone are different.

There are, though, a few things that tend to make most people more energetic:

- Working out (It helps me a lot).
- Getting 7+ hours of sleep.
- Listening to music, while developing.
- Don't work too much outside of the office, focusing on other projects can be *fun* but it can also be very *energy consuming*. Find the thin line.
- Find out new, exciting, ways to solve your tasks.
- Cut the lease on people you don't want to spend time with (for some that is very energy consuming).
- Eliminate potential stress factors.

etc, etc.

It's up to you to know how to gain more energy, but it's hard to tackle boredom over a single project. If you feel that you've gained 100% energy to work with at work but yet you're bored, well, you should probably just change a field.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe stop working on your own projects. There are projects that make you money (the one your employer asks you to do), and there are projects that don't make money (your own). If you don't work on your own projects, you probably won't get tired and feel sleepy on your work projects.

Comment: what about some development of skills to stay in market. Because where I work just get the job done no matter you know anything/not

Comment: I'd say the opposite, at least doing your own projects can "scratch that itch" of doing more interesting work.  The point you feel it's too much is when you think "is this all there is" on the boring stuff.  Use the home projects as a reward, get the day stuff done quick, and give you time to think about the home projects / r n r/ whatever.

Comment: @james, you do not need to work every day at skills development once or twice a year will get you there. Frankly you sound exhausted, so you need to drop the hobby in favor of your paying job until you have caught up on your sleep and then when you pick it back up, no more than an hour a day during the week and preferably only on weekends. You need the metal break from programming.